# Лямбда в C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Объясню что я хочу на примере C# кода

```
var a = 5;

// имеет тип Action
SomeGlobal = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

теперь в любом месте кода я могу выполнить `SomeGlobal.Invoke();` и в консоль выведется 5.

А вот плюсы не дают такого сделать. Плюсы ничего не знают о переменной `a` и как ее передать, если `SomeGlobal` типа **Action** безо всяких параметров я не представляю. Да и мне это не нужно, потому что та функция, которая будет выполнять эту лямбду тоже ничего не знает о переменной `a`.

Помогите записать это в С++/CLI

**UPD:**

В общем такая конструкция не работает

```
int a = 5;
SomeGlobal = gcnew Action([a]()
{
    Console::WriteLine(a);
});
```

**UPD2:**

Текст ошибки на английском выглядит так

> local lambda is not allowed in a member function of a managed class type

То есть я не могу в управляемом коде использовать лямбда-выражение?

Comment: Какой тип принимает конструктор `Action`?

Comment: @LapshinDmitry, это не имеет значение. Та же ошибка будет если просто написать `auto l = [](){ };`

Comment: В таком случае это какая-то особенность CLI, потому что в C++ это абсолютно валидный код. Интересно.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry, в функции main этот код рабочий, но когда это внутри ref class - уже не работает

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473127/c-cli-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-action