# C++/CLI делегаты, лямбда, Action

Tags: c++-cli

Есть, например, класс. Вот его заголовок

```
ref class MyClass
{
    public:
    void Execute();
    property Action^ Act;
}
```

Как мне из функции main задать для этого `Act` безымянную функцию? Хочу чтобы было как то так

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto mc = gcnew MyClass();
    mc->Act = [](){};
}
```

Получаю в этом случае ошибку, типа не верные аргументы для *MyClass::Act::set*

Оно и понятно, надо создавать новый Action. Делаю так

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto mc = gcnew MyClass();
    mc->Act = gcnew Action(nullptr, [](){});
}
```

Понимаю, что чего то тут не так написано... ну и соответственно ошибка "Недопустимый инициализатор делегата -- требуется функция".

Думаю, из примеров понятно, чего я хочу. Подскажите, как это осуществить.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473042/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-c-cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++/CLI умеет "делегаты", C++0x умеет "лямбды". Они не совместимы. Можно нагородить костыли http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277612/Using-lambdas-Cplusplus-vs-Csharp-vs-Cplusplus-CX

```
class LambdaRunner
{
  function<int(int)> _lambda;

public:
  LambdaRunner(function<int(int)> lambda) : _lambda(lambda)
  {
  } 

  int Run(int n)
  {
      return _lambda(n);
  }
};

ref class RefLambdaRunner
{
  LambdaRunner* pLambdaRunner;

  int Run(int n)
  {
    return pLambdaRunner->Run(n);
  }

public:
  RefLambdaRunner(function<int(int)> lambda)
  {
    pLambdaRunner = new LambdaRunner(lambda);
  }

  Func<int, int>^ ToDelegate()
  {
    return gcnew Func<int, int>(this, &RefLambdaRunner::Run);
  }

  void Close()
  {
    delete pLambdaRunner;
  }
};
```

Юзать так

```
auto lambda = [](int x) -> int { return x * 2; };
auto lambdaRunner = gcnew RefLambdaRunner(lambda);
int result  = lambdaRunner->ToDelegate()(10);
lambdaRunner->Close();
```

Короче C++/CLI не умеет нормальный C++, полная печаль.

Comment: что нужно подключить, чтобы использовать это `function<int(int)>`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: Да, я это нашел, но у меня нет класса std::function. Я не знаю почему.

Comment: Хедер functional заинклудили?

Comment: Ну все вроде заинклудил, копирую класс LambdaRunner, а он выдает кучу ошибок синтаксических на этапе компиляции. Причем не подчеркивает ничего. Ошибки, типа пропущены точки с запятой... Ничего не пропущено, ошибки левые какие то. Как отлавливать их, не представляю ((

Comment: На чистом проекте такая лажа? Может где то еще что то влияет что не в этом коде?

Comment: Поигрался с инклудами, все прошло )). Теперь другая беда. В примере используется функция, которая принимает 1 параметр int и возвращает int (`function<int(int)>`), а мне надо процедуру без параметров. `function<void(void)>` не канает :(

Comment: нашел. `function<void()>`. Однако все равно чего то не работает. Когда создаю объект RefLambdaRunner, студия подсказывает, что в списке его параметров не `function<void()>`, а <error-type>. Ну и компилятор не жрет лямбду, которую я отправляю в конструктор. В чем дело, не понимаю (((

Comment: Причем, если я напишу так `std::function<void()> f = []() { };`, то все норм отрабатывает

Comment: Шикарно! Все получилось! Кроме самого важного. Я не могу передать в лямбду экземпляр управляемого класса. То есть не могу написать так `[TheMyRefObject]() {};`, а без этого нет смысла в этом лямбда ранере (