# C++/CLI как передать в лямбда-функцию экземпляр управляемого класса?

Tags: c++-cli

Запилил управляемый запускатор для лямбды.

Помогли тут [C++/CLI делегаты, лямбда, Action](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473127/c-cli-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-action/473129?noredirect=1#comment532825_473129)

Теперь столкнулся с новой проблемой. Передавать в нее параметры я не могу, так как логика использования подразумевает `Action` (`function<void()>`). А сделать вот так я не могу

```
auto o = gcnew MyObject();
auto lr = gcnew RefLambdaRunner([o]()
{

});
```

Компилятор ругается, типа нельзя передать управляемый объект в лямбду. Помогите решить эту проблему.

Comment: Почему Вы упорно добавляете тег `c++` в вопросы, которые к настоящему c++ (ISO/IEC 14882) не имеют никакого отношения?

Comment: @alexolut Посмотрите, кто дал мне ответ. У него нет в подписках c++-cli. Не все, кто шарят в cli знают о существовании этой метки, к сожалению. :( Так что я и дальше буду подставлять эту метку. Уж извините

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать используя [`gcroot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/481fa11f.aspx). Но я бы не рекомендовал так поступать - потому что при таком подходе очень просто не уследить за какой-нибудь ссылкой, устроить циклическую зависимость - и привет утечка памяти.

Comment: Я не работал почти с нативным ++, поэтому не знаком с проблемами утечки памяти. У меня в функции main создается новый объект типа MyClass (теперь уже gcroot<MyClass^>) и передается в лямбду. По окончании функции main (конец программы) мне нужно что нибудь делать с этим созданным объектом? Или вы что-то другое имели ввиду?

Comment: @iRumba проблема в том, что этот `gcroot` будет захвачен лямбдой -и, таким образом, у вас будет *два* `gcroot`. Если теперь ваш объект будет иметь ссылку на эту лямбду - появится циклическая зависимость через неуправляемый код. Такие циклические зависимости GC "разруливать" не умеет.

Comment: Вроде понятно. Но в моем случае это вряд ли будет проблемой. Создаваемый gcroot мне нужен все время существования программы

Comment: А чем отличается передача в лямбду такая [theObject] от такой [&theObject]. Работают оба варианта в моем случае. В чем различие и как корректнее?

Comment: @iRumba это передача по значению и по ссылке. Если лямбда - долгоживущая, то второй вариант использовать нельзя.